# comparing two lists of lists with different sizes

Tags: python

I need to compare elements from individual list of lists. For example here are my two list:

```
listing = [['tl.48', 'tl.49', 'tl.57'], ['tl.23', 'tl.45', 'tl.12']];
search = [['tl.48','tl.57']];
```

Now my goal is to look for each item in search into each item in listing and if the two items `'tl.48'`, `'tl.57'` matches the items in listing then I choose that item from the listing and append it in an empty list. `listing[0]` has a size of 3 elements and `search[0][0]` and `search[0][1]` are present at `listing[0][0]` and `listing[0][2]`. How can I get `listing[0]` in a separate list and append it. If `listing[0]` is of size 4 and `search[0][0]` and `search[0][1]` are present in `listing[0]`, I will still add `listing[0]` to the new list. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I find your description hard to follow. Perhaps it would be easier if you gave the expected output...

Comment: appending is just done with... `my_list.append(my_new_element)`. So what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

```
[lst for lst in listing if all([True if term in lst else False for term in search[0]])]
```

Result: `[['tl.48', 'tl.49', 'tl.57']]`

This, for each `list` in `listing`, checks if each search term is `in` the `list`, only appending it if `all` such terms are there.

Note: search is a list containing a single list, which is why we use `search[0]`. If it's just the list of elements, use `search` instead.

Roughly equivalent to (same result, different method):

```
result = []
for lst in listing:
    valid = True
    for term in search[0]:
        if term not in lst:
            valid = False
    if valid:
        result.append(lst)
```

If this is going to be true list comparisons (where `search` and `listing` are both lists of lists), you'll need to find a more robust solution.

Comment: You can simplify that first line `all(term in lst for term in search[0])`